# Stream new files in S3 bucket into Kinesis

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to evaluate using Kinesis for stream processing log files. There is a separate process that uploads new logs into a S3 bucket - I can't touch that process. I want to know if there's a good way to stream new files that show up in the S3 log bucket *into* a Kinesis stream for processing. All documentation I've found so far covers using S3 as an output for the stream.

My current solution is to have a machine that constantly polls S3 for new files, downloads the new file to the local machine and streams it in using the Log4j appender. This seems inefficient. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is a really old question, but have a look at [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/).  It's perfect for your use case, as illustrated [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html).

In your case, you would setup the s3 event such that each new object added to the bucket invokes your lambda function.  In the lambda function you then write a few lines of code that read in the file and send the contents to the [PutRecord](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_PutRecord.html) (or [PutRecords](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_PutRecords.html) for batch) method for the Kinesis stream.

Not only will this work for your use case, but it's also awesome since it checks off a few buzzwords: "serverless" and "realtime"!