# How to put s3 data into kinesis stream?

Tags: amazon-web-services, scala, amazon-s3, flink-streaming, amazon-kinesis

We have data for the system logs getting dumped into s3 for backup service now we need to use that s3 data and send back into kinesis stream to process the lost data.What is the best way to do it from s3 to kinesis data stream?

s3 --> flink job --> kinesis stream via api

Comment: How big are these files? and in what format are they?

Comment: I think this is what you're after: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/streaming-data-from-amazon-s3-to-amazon-kinesis-data-streams-using-aws-dms/

Comment: files are of 200mb size per hour

Comment: This may be relevant: someone answered this a couple years back here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25916540/stream-new-files-in-s3-bucket-into-kinesis